# What means this classes in <nav>

Tags: html

```
  <header class="nk-header">
    <!--
    START: Navbar

    <nav class="nk-navbar nk-navbar-top nk-navbar-sticky nk-navbar-transparent nk-navbar-white-text-on-top">
    <div class="container">
```

This is bootstrap framework, or what ? I tried understand this, google it, but fail.

Comment: This looks like a theme produced by https://nkdev.info/ Have you read their docs?

Comment: Yeah, i was read already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's Godlike-html ...Classes ...

**There Is Multiple Style Classes are define to** `<nav> .. </nav>`

> 1. nk-navbar : For Style to Navbar
> 2. nk-navbar-top : For Fixed Nav Bar On Top
> 3. .nk-navbar-sticky – sticky navbar on page scroll
> 4. .nk-navbar-transparent – transparent background color
> 5. .nk-navbar-white-text-on-top – white text when menu on the top of page (not sticky)

**For Reference** .. https://nkdev.info/docs/godlike-html/template-structure/side-navigation/